# Drupal 7 not working with oracle database

Tags: oracle, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I installed with a fresh drupal installation(D7) and followed the steps mentioned in ReadMe file for Oracle driver:

```
HOW TO INSTALL ORACLE SUPPORT IN DRUPAL 7

EXTRACT FILES

cd /includes/database/
tar xzvf
cd oracle/module
mv oracle /sites/all/modules
```

> > After this when I run the install.php I cannot see the "Oracle" as database type can you please tell me what is missed?
> >     Only Mysql postgressql and SQlite are the options coming..

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the pdo_oci extension enabled?

See http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php